# How can I download and install styles separately from MiKTeX?

Tags: packages, miktex

Compiling my .tex files gives me errors such as missing the required styles and libraries. For example like this:

```
Pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is pdfTex, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 <MiKTeX 22.3> <preloaded format = pdflatex.fmt>
Restricted \write18 enabled.
Entering extended mode
<C:/Users/ B/Documents/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
<C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
<C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo>>
<C:\ Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
========================================================================
Unfortunately, the package Cyrillic could not be installed.
Please check the log file:
C:\Users\  B  \AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
========================================================================

Package foentenc Error: Encoding file ‘t2aenc.def’ not found.
<fontenc>       You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.

See the fontenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H<return> for immediate help.
…
l.111 \ProcessOptions*
```

Therefore, I've tried to install such libraries separately. The MiKTeX has (https://miktex.org/packages/markdown/files) different additions for perfect compilation of different types of files and libraries usage. But I didn't find how can I get them (github suggests from different authors)
How can I get .sty separately?

Comment: It's probably easiest to use the package manager that comes with MikTeX, i.e. the MiKTeX Console. Downloading from CTAN is another option, but is generally a little bit more difficult.

Comment: You should install them in a`LocalTeXMF`  directory, respecting the structure of a TeX directory, and you declare it  through `MiKTeX Settings`.

Comment: I think I should re-install my MiKTeX, because it cannot install packages even from the console mode with administrator rights. It always shows the SSL connect error

Comment: That SSL error might just be a bad mirror with an expired SSL cert. You could just choose a different mirror.

Comment: Try TeXLive, by default make a full installation and therefore take some time, but after that, very rarely you will need download anything else. The bad news are that packages are upgradable  only for some moths, them the year version is frozen, and you must to expect some time to install (better that upgrade) the next version, but once installed properly, no problem of downloads at demand.

Comment: Thank you all for advice. Will follow and try my best. Going to tell later if this problem with packages will be solved